# How to set Chrome Window Name on launch via CLI or other automation

Tags: windows-10, command-line, google-chrome, automation

As of Chrome 90, there is a built-in feature under "(three dots menu) > More tools > Name window..." which allows you to rename a window. This can be very handy for a multitude of reasons, such as Alt+Tab recognition, among other such as targeting specific Chrome instances for capturing and recording or live streaming.

Is there any way to launch Chrome with a custom name already set for that instance (such as a command-line argument)? If not, how would I go about automating the setting of this, such as through a F12 > Console script, or javascript: bookmarklet, which I could then invoke as part of the CLI launch?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously. I need this too.
With many chrome windows all running different profiles, setting it to the profile name would be fantastic, or, even better:

```
<profile-name>-<label>
```

to differentiate additional use cases.

Does not appear to be supported: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1190160

Answer (score 2):

`--window-name="whatever"` works with Chrome 120.0.6099.71 on Mac OS. For example:

```
open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --window-name="Hi Bob" --new-window https://www.google.com
```

..click the "Window" menu. "Hi Bob" should be listed with the open windows at the bottom of the dropdown.

As of 2023-12-14, this arg was listed in (added to?) the link that Bruce Edge provided:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-name

> Specify the initial window user title: --window-name="My custom title"