# Can a keyboard shortcut be assigned to Name Window function (under More Tools) of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I read the question about programmatically setting the window name in chrome,
[How to set Chrome Window Name on launch via CLI or other automation](https://superuser.com/questions/1712287/how-to-set-chrome-window-name-on-launch-via-cli-or-other-automation). There doesn't seem to be an answer.

It would help though to have a keyboard shortcut to naming a chrome tab.
Is *that* possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a keyboard shortcut to set the name of a chrome window (tab).

Answer (score 0):

This requires a Chrome extension, but it needs to be done
differently than what you're describing.

See the extension
[Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai) :

> Take control of your tabs:
>
> - Rename tab
> - Change tab icon
> - Pin tab
> - Prevent tab closing
> - Unique tab
> - Mute tab
>
> You have to define your rules from the Options page. Quick rename can
> be done by right-clicking anywhere in the page and click on "Rename
> Tab".

Comment: Looks good. My organizations does not allow me using extensions, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunate. Besides an extension, I can think of a bookmarklet that will use JavaScript to ask for text and set the title of the active tab to it.